# Stop R as.h2o load from converting blanks into NAs

Tags: r, h2o

Whenever I transfer my data into h2o from R, the h2o server appears to convert any blanks into NA - I want to be able to differentiate the two cases.

This happens when i use `as.h2o(mydata)` or if i save the data to a csv, then load it into h2o through the R interface via `data.table::fwrite()` then `h2o.uploadFile()`. I noticed that as.h2o replicated the fwrite, uploadFile steps so I would prefer to rely on it since it has some other checks.

I've noticed that h2o code has a single na string of "NA_h2o" so I'm not sure why it also handles empties the same way.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

you can specify how you would like NAs to be interpreted with the `na.strings` parameter in `h2o.importFile()` which by default is `NULL` (and is likely the reason your blanks are getting converted to NAs).

more details on the documentation of `h2o.importFile()` can be found here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.importFile.html

Comment: Thanks but no i have tried na.strings and the default if you look at h2o code is that it used "NA_h2o" as the na string in it's conversion - also, given as.h2o takes an R frame converts to csv and then calls importFile (or maybe uploadFile - they are similar)

Comment: @SimonR can you provide a few rows so i can test out your issue. in the following example, you'll see that as.h2o distinguishes between blank ' ' and NA : `df <- data.frame(a = c(1:3,NA,4:6),b=c(letters[1:6],NA), c= c(1,NA,runif(5)))` `df[1,1] <- ' '` `dh <- as.h2o(df)`